# add / at the end of each line

Tags: sed, files, filesystems

I want to add this character at the end of each line in a file:

```
sed -e 's/$/\/$/g' myfile.txt > myfile_new.txt
```

The result add `$/` with explicit $ in each line. but I do not want to add $.

For example, this is a line in the original file:

```
https://myline
```

I executed the command, the result become:

```
https://myline/$
```

But I want:

```
https://myline/
```

What is wrong? Plz note that the file was originally `dos` type, I convert it to `unix` using:

```
dos2unix myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need `'s/$/\//'` - the `$` *anchors* the pattern to the end of the line, but it's not an actual character that can be replaced. Similarly for `^`. What you're actually matching (and replacing) is the empty pattern anchored at the end of the line.

Also as noted by @Phillippos in the comments, the `g` is unnecessary here: since the expression is anchored, it can only match at one place.

Comment: 1) As there is only one end-of-line per line, the `g` option is not neccessary (true for all anchored patterns) 2) If the pattern or replacement contains a slash, better use a different delimiter: `s_$_/_` is easier to read.

Comment: another "in other words..." -- the left-hand side of `s///` is a _regular expression_; the right-hand side is a _plain string_ (except for `&` and `\1`...). When you put a `$` in the right-hand side, you're adding a plain character.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with awk command too

command

```
awk '{print $0"/"}' filename
```